# Laravel - how to check if field exists in eloquent query with leftJoin and orWhere

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have query:

```
$id = 16;

$orders = (new Order)->where(['orders.id' => $id])
        ->leftJoin('transactions', 'orders.id', '=', 'transactions.order_id')
        ->leftJoin('cards', 'cards.id', '=', 'transactions.card_id')
        ->orWhere('email', '=', 'aaaa@aaaa.com')
        ->orWhere('last4', '=', '5555')
        ->get();
```

If transactions have card everything is fine, but if card_id in transactions table is NULL error appears:
"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'last4' in 'where clause".

How I can elegant solve this ?
How to check if column "last4" exists ?

PS.

last4 is in table "cards.last4"

Comment: Where do you have such column?

Comment: get the sql of the query through ->toSql() instead of ->get() to see where it goes amiss.